# ElasticSearch Script Field return incorrect value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with `cd` field is 44.4
When i using "script_fields as below :

```
"doc['cd'].value + 1"
```

`script_fields` value will return `45.400001525878906`

Please help me to use `script_fields` value return to `45.4`

Comment: Now check with the below. Know me if any query. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For rounding up your floating point values use `Math.round()` function. 
The below will return the value after two decimal places.

```
Math.round(doc['your_custom_type_var'].value * 100.0)/100.0
```

If you want to round up after 3 decimal places then change the value as like:

```
Math.round(doc['your_custom_type_var'].value * 1000.0)/1000.0
```

For your case do the followings :

```
Math.round((doc['cd'].value + 1) * 10.0 - 0.5 )/10.0 // -0.5 for getting the correct result. For this 45.401 and 45.601 both will return 45.6
```

**Notes**

`Math.round()` function returns the closest int to the argument. For example

```
Math.round(45.40000152) // will return the value 45
Math.round(45.60000152) // will return the value 46
```

To get the correct answer you can substitute `0.5` to the actual number and then rounding up.Then it will return the value which we want to get.

First we multiple the value with 10.0 for moving the decimal place one unit right(for the above value `454.0000152`). After rounding this cuts of the floating point values(for the above value `454`), and so we divide the whole numbers by `10.0` for getting the value which rounded up by one decimal place from the actual value(for the above value `45.4`).

Think, it will help.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But cd filed is dynamic value (ex: 44.2, 44.674). So, the value will be wrong when i applying your solution. I want to script_fields that will return to 45.2, 45.674

Comment: You need to define the decimal point place you want to see. for example 1,2 or three. If you want to make dynamic position set. then use `Math.pow(base, power)` in the place of 10.0. Give feedback if any query

Comment: And for rounding problem, I am fixing my answer

Comment: Now, check the answer.